# Need help on datetime manipulation in python

Tags: python

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print ('Today is: ' + str(today))

//returns Today is: 2016-10-06
```

How could I manipulate the output to look like this: 
"Today is: October 6, 2016"

Comment: Have you looked at `datetime.strftime` ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: I realize the question asks for python but this is a super simple one liner in bash: `echo "Today is: $(date +'%B%e, %Y')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print('Today is: ' + today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")) # Today is: October 06, 2016
```

Where:

- `%B` - Month as locale’s full name
- `%d` - Day of the month
- `%Y` - Year with century as a decimal number

Answer (score 0):

Modified your program slightly using    `strftime(' %B %d %Y')`

**Working Code**

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today().strftime(' %B %d %Y')
```

print ('Today is: ' + today)

**OUTPUT:**

```
> ================================ RESTART =========================
Today is:  October 06 2016
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

print ('Today is: ' + today.strftime("%B %d , %Y"))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.